# RTFM: a discord bot which runs code and queries documentations

Tags: app, python, chatbot

*This post is to ensure the bot described can use the API with a key ; it can search questions from any SE website*

This bot is still in development. However a stable version is already running 24/7 (and already on a few servers), which you can invite from [here](https://discordbots.org/bot/495914599531675648)

It can evaluate code (don't worry, outside of it, and using a safe API) in for the moment 580 languages (the amount keeps increasing, slowly), a list being available on the [Github](https://github.com/FrenchMasterSword/RTFMbot) as well as the documentations and references already available. Indeed you can, from Discord, search through documentations like the C++ one and even display pages of references like Debian man pages or HTML tags.

Here is an example of code execution in Kotlin : [image: Screenshot from discord, showing command run and bot's answer]

*To avoid blocking, the API used also limits time and resources given to a program*

Another example, of searching through documentations : [image: Screenshot from discord, showing command doc and bot's answer]

And another last example, of displaying a reference : [image: Screenshot from discord, showing command ref and bot's answer]

The source code is licensed under MPl 2.0. You can freely add it to your Discord server.

*Note : its prefix is `do` with a space behind*